# Changing config params without server reload in sails.js

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible for Sails.js app to understand config file changes without having to restart server ? I want to add routes and change Mail server config params without server reboot. sails-hook-autoreload, seems to only cover models, controllers and services.

What are my options? I really do not want to restart the server when there are so many users logged into the app.

Please help. Thanks for reading the post

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible because the configs are only loaded into the app during start up. Your best bet to do scheduled maintenance and bring the app down and restart do your testing and then reopen the app to users.

I am not sure how to use it but I hear containers like Docker may be another solution where you containerize your app and use it to push updates out. Haven't used it but that could be a solution.

Comment: Thank you for lighting reply. Should I store all changeable config variables into service file and then use sails-hook-autoreload to auto load. ?

Will try it out.

Comment: I would want to control when my production app reloads so I personally wouldn't use an autoreload.